# Visual studio won't recognised "manually" created source files (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, compilation

Hi I'm trying to create a Hello World C++ program starting from an Empty Project. In the directory in **Windows Explorer** I create a Main.cpp file with the main() function. It is visible in the folder view but **NOT** the solution view, and the program doesn't build because it isn't aware of Main.cpp.

Anyone know why this is happening? Surely there's some setting I can change to make it actually look for the .cpp files that are in the directory rather than have to always create them through the solution panel?

Comment: You can add files to the project. Visual studio only builds files in the project, it doesn't matter where files are stored

Comment: If there's a setting to make VS seek out and auto-add files, I've yet to find it.

Comment: ... and you can add more than one file at a time (just use multiple select)